# Автоматическое исполнение кода

Tags: веб-программирование, java-ee, рефлексия

Здравствуйте. Мне необходимо реализовать автоматическое исполнение кода. Имеется какая-то задача (например, программа должна вывести сумму чисел, которые поданы на вход как параметры). Пользователь вводит код на Java в input (textarea) поле. Нажимает выполнить и должно происходить сначала проверка на корректность кода, автоматическое исполнение и тестирование этого кода. (Как, например, на www.codecademy.com). 
Какие у Вас могут быть предложения по этому поводу?

Comment: копировать в файл то что введено и компилировать через командную строку.

Comment: @pavel  А как тогда проверять правильность выполнения исходного кода?

Comment: @GermanSevostyanov по тестам... Программе дают на вход пример и смотрят что вывело. Самый простой вариант `run.exe < 1.in > 1.out && diff 1.out 1.ans` Иногда не просто в лоб сравнение а использование чекера. Можно конечно почитать исходники какой-нибудь системы типо `Ejudge`

Comment: @pavel вообще да, идея мне нравится.

Comment: Неплохо бы всё это делать в какой-то песочнице, а то пользователь введёт что-нибудь вроде `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rm -rf /");` и всё сломает.